# Sort Order in Django Running PostgreSQL on CentOS

Tags: django, postgresql

I am running CentOS 6.5, PostgreSQL 8.4.18 and Django 1.6.

I'm having trouble finding the correct collation settings for the Postgres database (Lc_collate and Lc_ctype) to achieve my desired sort order.

The language of the site is en_US.

Encoding is UTF8.

I would like SQL queries to sort ignoring case, and with symbols at the top of the list.

So if I have a Django model called "ListingType", when I do:

```
ListingType.objects.all()
```

I would like this to be the ordering

```
*This has a Symbol
Aardvark
baby
Bat
cat
Dance
This doesn't have a symbol
```

I can get the * to sort at the top sometimes, but this causes all lower case items to sort at the bottom of the list.
When I achieve case being ignored and the lower case items being in the middle of the list where expected, the * sorts in the middle as well as if it were ignoring the presence of the symbol (instead of jumping it to the top).

Does anybody know what settings to use when creating the database to account for symbols AND be case insensitive to achieve the desired order listed above?

---

Edit:

This sort order works nicely in MySQL when using the utf8_general_ci collation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PostgreSQL string functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html) to help you get the order you're seeking.

For example:

```
SELECT name FROM city
    ORDER BY
            LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1), '([a-zA-Z]+)', '')) DESC,
            LOWER(name) DESC;
```

The first clause gets the first character of the string, and replaces it with `''` if the character is alphabetic. We can then sort whether the length of this new string is `0` or `1` (it's `1` if non-alphabetic).

If your data isn't ASCII-compatible, you should instead replace a designated set of "special characters" with `''` (using the `REGEXP_REPLACE` function) and switch the sort to ascending.

The second clause ensures the rest of the result is sorted in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: This would require doing custom SQL in Django. This is a valid option, though I was hoping to have a solution that would work nicely with the whole Django ORM.

Comment: Django isn't going to have chained methods for individual RDBMS-specific functions. You can use [`extra() QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) method to escape the ORM only for the `ORDER BY` clause and keep your code cleaner.